# Prove that random variable Z=X+Y has a probability density function (pdf) and calculate it.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X and Y be independent random variables. The random variable X has probability density function p(x) and Y is a discrete random variable having just two values: 1 with probability 1/3 and 2 with probability 2/3.

Since Z is the sum of two random variables it is known that the sum of two probability distributions is another probability distribution. To calculate:

$P(X + Y \leq x)$
$= \sum_{k=1}^2P(X + k \leq x)P(Y = k) = P(X + 1 \leq x)P(Y = 1) + P(X + 2 \leq x)P(Y = 2)$

$=P(X \leq x - 1)(1/3) +P(X \leq x - 2)(2/3)$

$=F_X(x - 1)(1/3) + F_X(x - 2)(2/3)$

Now, to find the pdf of one must take the derivative of the CDF with respect to x $\implies $

$f_Z(x) = (F_X(x - 1)(1/3) + F_X(x - 2)(2/3))'$

$= 1/3*f_X(x-1)+2/3*f_X(x-2)$

Comment: What is the trouble with this?  Please show what work and thoughts you have so far, so that people can see where you are having difficulty.

Comment: If $Z=X+Y$ then you cannot say $p_Z(z) = p_X(x) + p_Y(y)$

Comment: @Henry Okay, I tried to attempt the problem a different way

Answer (score 1):

Try to calculate $P(X+Y \le x )$ by conditionning by the value of Y , formally 
$P(X+Y \le x ) = \sum_{k=0} P(X+k \le x ) P(Y=k)$

Comment: Hi Kupoc I attempted your suggestion and got to this point not sure how to continue

Comment: Thank you @Kupoc!

Answer (score 1):

Your edited answer of $$F_Z(x)=P(X + Y \leq x)=F_X(x - 1)(1/3) + F_X(x - 2)(2/3)$$ is correct.  But it is a cumulative distribution function, so now take the derivative with respect to $x$ to give the density function $$f_Z(x)=\tfrac13 f_X(x - 1) + \tfrac23 f_X(x - 2)$$

Comment: Thank you, Henry!